# Unit testing Avro Generic deseralisation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

In my spark job I save a dataset to Avro format with:

```
val ds: Dataset[Foo] = ...
ds.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).avro(path)
```

In a downstream application I parse the Avro files with a custom deserialiser:

```
def foo(record: GenericRecord): Foo = Foo(
  bar = record.get("bar").asInstanceOf[Int]
  baz = record.get("baz").asInstanceOf[Utf8].toString
)
```

I want to write a spec for the custom parser without having to bring Spark into the dependencies for the downstream app. But I am uncertain about how to emulate the serialisation behaviour in Spark. The Spark source has a lot of custom handling outside of Avro itself.

Can I reliably emulate Spark Avro serialisation to use as input for my spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a spec that simulates Spark's avro auto-schema generation in a non-spark environment and tests the ser/de.

```
  private val sconf = new SparkConf().set("spark.sql.avro.compression.codec", "snappy")

  implicit val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkTest").master("local[*]").config(sconf).getOrCreate()

  implicit def sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext

  "a foo" should {
    "serialise to/from avro" in {
      val foo = Foo("bar")
      val tempPath = "./foo_avro"
      val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(foo), 1)
      val jsonRdd = rdd.map(_.toJson)
      spark.read.json(jsonRdd).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).avro(tempPath)

      val readItBack = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(tempPath,
                                           classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
                                           classOf[AvroKey[GenericRecord]],
                                           classOf[NullWritable])

      val foos: Set[Foo] =
        readItBack.keys.map(x => FooAvroParser(x.datum()).parse).collect().toSet
      FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(tempPath))

      foos mustEqual Set(foo)
    }.set(minTestsOk = 5)
```

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "3.2.0" % "test" exclude ("org.apache.avro", "avro"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1" % "test",
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.7.7"
)
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7" % "test",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7" % "test",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7" % "test"
)
```

Comment: So, you create a case class, then generate a schema from it using spark. If spark is working correctly, you _know_ what the result that will yield. The unit testing is about testing your own component, not how spark generates schema. You can just assume, that spark does what is supposed to, and give your test the pre-created schema rather than "simulating" it being generated every time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to emulate serialization, you just need to create a `GenericRecord`:

```
 val gr = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema)
   .put("bar", 10)
   .put("baz", "bat")
   .build

 foo(gr) shouldBe Foo(10, "baz")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't necessarily replicate what Spark is doing. The bugs I want to prevent in the parser are 1 field name is wrong, 2 field type is wrong. e.g. my test and parser might both assume a field called `"bar"`, but it's actually `"bar_id"`.

Comment: That's what avro schema is for. If the schema says the name is "bar", it, can't be "bar_id", regardless of what spark does.

Comment: The missing piece is how to generate the schema at test time. In the doc I only see a method to generate a schema from the terminal.

Comment: Spark autogenerates the schema, so there is no schema to work with on the test side.

Comment: Well, the idea is that you should know exactly what schema spark will generate. You can just store it somewhere and use in your tests. Verifying spark schema generation should not be concern of your unit testing - spark has its own tests for that.

Comment: If the schema was part of the app, sure. But in this case, everyone would have to update the test schema when they change the case classes. They need to 1 know that they need to; 2 know how to do it & 3 remember each time. That's not sustainable.

Comment: In your answer, if I change the case class to `Foo(bar: Int, bad: String)` the spec would not fail, but the app would. So it's not useful as a test.

Comment: If the class becomes in compatible with the schema, sure, the test would fail. What makes you think it would not?

Comment: It is actually the other way around: _your_ code will not fail if you change the class, because it just reads back whatever it writes, not what _should be_ written.

Comment: I don't think you understand my setup. The case class is defined once, in a dependancy. If I change the case class and update dependencies without changing the parser then my app will fail, my test will fail and your test will not, because your test is not doing what spark does.

Comment: If the case class is defined  in the dependency, than there is no way you can change it.